# How can I optimize the code reducing the similar repetitive parameters

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, j2html

I want to optimize this code instead of using `td(String.valueof(dataset.get()))` mutliple times. I am relatively new to lambda expressions usage and not able to figure out a better way than this

Code need to be optimized

```
  return table(thead(tr(each(columnHeaders, header -> 
  th(String.valueOf(header))))),
  tbody(each(myList, dataset ->
  tr(td(String.valueOf(dataset.get(0))), 
  td(String.valueOf(dataset.get(1))), 
  td(String.valueOf(dataset.get(2))), 
  td(String.valueOf(dataset.get(3))), 
  td(String.valueOf(dataset.get(4))),
  td(String.valueOf(dataset.get(5))), 
  td(String.valueOf(dataset.get(6))), 
  td(String.valueOf(dataset.get(7))), 
  td(String.valueOf(dataset.get(8))), 
  td(String.valueOf(dataset.get(9))),
  td(String.valueOf(dataset.get(10)))

      ))
  )
)
```

Comment: What this supposed to create as output? And what prevents you from writing a loop statement?

Comment: Seems you want to create a DSL. Imho Java isn't the best language for that.

Comment: How many arguments does "tr" method have?

Comment: What exactly do you want to optimize? Code style or performance? If it's the latter one, what performance problem do you have?

Comment: What library are you using?  What is the method `each`? We can help a little better.  If `dataset` is `Iterable`, then you can use `forEach` on it and do like you did with `columnHeaders`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see, you're using j2html.

I think you can do this in one line like this:

```
return table(thead(tr(each(columnHeaders, header -> th(String.valueOf( tbody(each(myList, dataset -> each(dataset, data -> td(data)))))
```

But it probably reads better if you break it out a little bit:

```
return table(thead(tr(each(columnHeaders, 
                           header -> th(String.valueOf(header))))),
             tbody(each(myList, 
                        dataset -> each(dataset, data -> td(String.valueOf(data))))));
```

All that I've done here, is inside your call to `tbody` you say `each(myList...`, then just do `each` again for every element of `myList`.

If you made sure that `columnHeaders` and `myList` were typed collections (like `List<String>`) then you could do something like this:

```
return table(thead(tr(each(columnHeaders, TagCreator::header))),
             tbody(each(myList, 
                        dataset -> each(dataset, TagCreator::td))));
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what library you're using so have made an assumption for `tr()` and `td()` return types:

```
private TR trOf(List<?> dataset, int startIdx, int endIdxInclusive) {
    List<TD> tds = IntStream.rangeClosed(startIdx, endIdxInclusive).map(i -> tdOf(dataset, i)).collect(Collectors.toList());

    return tr(tds.toArray(new TD[0]));
}

private TD tdOf(List<?> dataset, int idx) {
    return td(String.valueOf(dataset.get(idx));
}
```

Then:

```
return table(thead(tr(each(columnHeaders, header -> 
th(String.valueOf(header))))),
tbody(each(myList, dataset ->
trOf(dataSet,0,10)

    ))
)
```

Comment: Probably j2html, as that HTML builder library is tagged with the question. Thus I guess it is not his library, so your idea might not work for him.